# Why didn't this question get automatically deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24396/how-to-work-with-an-argumentative-qa-engineer-at-software-house

My understanding is a question at -3 with no answers closed several months ago should have been automatically deleted.

I cannot vote to delete/downvote however since the question is locked due to a failed migration.

Comment: Hmm.  I suspect the lock (automatically generated when the migration failed) is to blame.  For science, I could try removing the lock and seeing if the Roomba gets it.

Answer (score 2):

As [Monica says](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/why-didnt-this-question-get-automatically-deleted#comment6098_2773) probably because it was locked due to the failed migration. As it had no answers, and was of no value to our community, it has been manually removed for the time being.